# Progress bar with steps styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

How to style my progress bar so it looks like the design? I tried to moved the text but they keep staying in the circle. Also not sure how to create the circle within another circle dot with css. It should be non clcikable. Here is the css and html files. Also not sure how to let active/finished steps be in a tick icon.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>XXXXXX</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="progress">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    <ul id="progress-text">
      <li class="step active">1</li>
      <li class="step">2</li>
      <li class="step">3</li>
      <li class="step">4</li>
      <li class="step">5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="progress-prev" class="btn" disabled>Prev</button>
  <button id="progress-next" class="btn">Next</button>
  <script src="./bar script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

--------------------- css file

#progress {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #4584ff;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

#progress-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#progress-text::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#progress-text .step {
  border: 3px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#progress-text .step.active {
  border-color: #4584ff;
  background-color: #4584ff;
  color: #fff;
  
}

.btn {
  background: lightgray;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

Here is the reference picture

[image: Reference pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that's what you meant

```css
#progress {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #4584ff;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

#progress-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#progress-text::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#progress-text .step {
  border: 3px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#progress-text .step.active {
  border-color: #4584ff;
  background-color: #4584ff;
  color: #4584ff;
  
}

.btn {
  background: lightgray;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

/* added css */
#progress-text .step {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

#progress-text .step label{
  margin-top:120%;
  font-size:.7rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-color:inherit;
}

#progress-text .step.active::after {
  content:"✓";
  color:#fff;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  top:2px;
  left:8px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  
}

#progress-text .step.progress{
  border-color:#4584ff;

}

#progress-text .step.progress::after{
  content:"•";
  transform:scale(3);
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:1.5px;
  color:#4584ff;
}

#progress-text .step.progress label{
  color:#4584ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    <ul id="progress-text">
      <li class="step active">
        <label>Review</label>
      </li>
      <li class="step active">
        <label>Assignment</label>
      </li>
      <li class="step progress">
        <label>Investigation</label>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <label>Handling</label>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <label>Resolution</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="progress-prev" class="btn" disabled>Prev</button>
  <button id="progress-next" class="btn">Next</button>
```

Comment: You might need a bit of javascript to make it work

Comment: Of course, but the question wasn't about that

Comment: I just thought that they also had a desired transition effect but sure ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AntekPietryga  Thank you so much! Any idea on how to create the dot inside the circle?

Comment: @hopetocodebetter The dot can be done in multiple ways. The simplest I can think of is by using a pseudo-element like `:before` and `:after` and styling it to be a centered blue dot

Comment: @hopetocodebetter - snippet updated with dot